# Transforming atoms in prolog variables

Tags: prolog

If I have a list of atoms, is it possible transform that in a list of prolog variables? If yes, anyone can give me an example?

Example:
`?- atom_to_variable([x1, x2, x3], V).
V = [X1, X2, X3].`

Comment: Can you show an example use case for this? What are you wanting to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I'm working in a exercise who consists in solve boolean satisfiability problems. I'm trying to read an entry, check who are the atoms and build a truth table. Example: with the entry `?- sat("(x1#x2)")` (# = or), I need find the atoms x1, x2, build a truth table for 2 variables, get the columns of the table and say that the variable X1 = Column1 and X2 = Column2. Point out that I don't know yet if this is in fact a good option to start solving the exercise, but is something that I thought and I'm curious to know if it's possible to do.

Comment: So you just need to build a truth table for any given boolean expression with some number of variables in it?

Comment: Basically yes. After that I need check if the expression is satisfiable, or in other words, check if any combination of boolean values for the expression evaluates to true (but that run away from the question and furthermore I'll see how that can be solved).

Comment: If you build the truth table, then it should be obvious if any results are true, right?

Comment: In fact you're right. Now I see that It's not mandatory make this transformation.